# Суффиксы в словах «лесник и «мясник»

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор, суффиксы

Лес — лесной — лесник. Это понятно. Но если в слове "мясник" суффикс -НИК-, то тогда мясо — мясник? А где "мясной"? Почему так?
Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в слове "лесник" суффиксы -Н- и -ИК-, а в слове "мясник" суффикс -НИК-?

Answer (score 2):

Но как это объяснить шестиклассникам на уроке?

Детям надо говорить правду, но на том уровне, который они могут понять.  И надо учить их работать со словарями.

У нас есть два суффикса – «ик» и «ник».  Суффикс «ик» используется, если слово образуется от  п  р и л а г а т е л ь н о г о, а суффикс «ник» используется, если слово образуется от  с у щ е с т в и т е л ь н о г о.

В толковом словаре написано: ЛЕСНИК, - м. Лесной сторож; работник лесного хозяйства. МЯСНИК,  м. 1. Продавец мяса, торговец мясом.

Если слово образуется и определяется через существительное, то выделяем суффикс «ник»:  мясо – мяс-ник. Если слово образуется и определяется через прилагательное, то выделяем суффикс «ик»: лесн/ой – лесн/ик.

Если же словари дают разное толкование, то это тоже можно учесть. К примеру, в словообразовательном словаре приведены два варианта на любой вкус: лес – лес/ник и лесной – лесн/ик.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что в *обоих* случаях можно разглядеть суффикс прилагательного **-н-**. Если где-то толкуют эти слова по-разному, то опираются на семантику, причем без достаточных оснований. Слово "лесник" может трактоваться как упрощение от "лес**н**ой работник/обходчик", а слово "мясник" - как упрощение от "мяс**н**ой торговец". Поэтому нет смысловых причин противопоставлять торговца мясным товаром мясному бульону и утверждать, что слово "мясник" образовано *непосредственно* от существительного "мясо".

Comment: _Слѣдовательно, **мясной торговецъ** долженъ погибнуть отъ торговца кожей?_ (из старого сборника комедий Аристофана). Можно найти сей "термин" также у Ключевского, Соловьева и других авторов, которые ближе к истокам словообразования.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с **Alex_ander** : в обоих случаях можно разглядеть суффикс прилагательного **-н-**.

Вот, к примеру, что пишет Потиха (*"Современное русское словообразование"*):

> Не трудно отграничить суффикс ***-ик*** от производного суффикса
> ***-ник***, который образовался от суффикса ***-ик*** и суффикса прилагательного ***-н-***. <…> Если в языке существует соответствующее
> прилагательное с суффиксом ***-н-***, то в данном слове есть два
> суффикса: ***-н-*** и ***-ик***…

И выделяет Потиха в своём словаре *"Строение русского слова"* (1981) суффиксы ***-н-*** и ***-ик*** и в слове *лесник*, и в слове *мясник*: лес/н/ик, мяс/н/ик.

Что же до Тихонова…

В его *"Морфемно-орфографическом словаре"* приведены два возможных варианта членения на морфемы слова *лесник*: "1. лес/ни́к/ 1 (от лес/). 2. лес/н/и́к 2 (от лес/н/о́й)" — и  только один вариант членения слова *мясник*: мяс/ник/. Почему так — мог бы сказать только сам Тихонов, но…  (К сожалению, этот его словарь грешит очень многими неточностями.)

В своём же двухтомном *"Словообразовательном словаре"* Тихонов говорит о возможности вариативных образований не только слова  *лесник*, но и слова *мясник*:

> лес -> лес-**ник** 1; лес-**н**(ой) -> лесн-**ик** 2
>
> мяс(о) -> мяс-**ник** 1; мяс-**н**(ой) -> мясн-**ик** 2

Из *"Словообразовательного словаря"* Тихонова:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]